# Отслеживать клик django

Tags: python, django

Как я могу сделать так что при нажати на `<a href=""></a>`
заработало функция django?

Я попробовал так, но при перезагрузке страницы тоже работает функция. Нужен чтоб только при нажатии.

Мой код:

```
<a name="liked" href="">
    <p class="likediz" style="float: right;">
        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
        {{ instance.dizlike }}
    </p>
</a>
```

views

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    like = HttpResponse("liked")
    if like:
        instance.like += 1
        instance.save
```

И ещё было бы круто, чтобы пользователь только один раз мой поставить лайк или дизлайк.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположу, что оценка тоже делается для статей.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum, Case, When, Value


# Модель для хранения голоса пользователя
# за или против статьи
class Vote(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Пользователь', related_name='+')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, verbose_name='Статья')
    positive = models.BooleanField('За')


class Article(models.Model):
    ...

    # Свойство возвращающее сумму голосов 'За'
    # с вычетом голосов 'Против'
    @property
    def votes(self):
        return (self.vote_set
                    .annotate(value=Case(When(positive=True, then=Value(1)),
                                         When(positive=False, then=Value(-1)),
                                         default=Value(0)))
                    .aggregate(Sum('value'))
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required  # только аутентифицированные пользователи могут голосовать
def vote(request, pk, reaction):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)

    vote, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(voter=request.user, article=article,
                                               defaults={'positive': reaction})

    # Если уже есть голос этого пользователя за эту
    # статью, то возвращаем ошибку 403
    if not created:
        return HttpResponseForbidden('Голосовать можно только один раз')

    # Перенаправляем пользователя на ту страницу
    # с которой был отправлен голос или
    # на ту статью, за которую он был отправлен.
    next = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', article)
    return redirect(next)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^vote/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<reaction>up|down)/$', vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**article.html**

```
<div class="votes">
    <a href="{% url 'vote' instance.pk 'down' %}">
        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
    </a>
    <span>
       {{ instance.votes }}
    </span>
    <a href="{% url 'vote' instance.pk 'up' %}">
        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Только есть один нюанс, так как голосование - это не идемпотентная операция, она должна осуществляться через форму методом POST, а не по ссылке. Иначе браузер может проголосовать за пользователя, просто подгружая страницы возможных переходов.

Comment: Огромное спасибо вы мне очень помогаете развиваться !

Comment: А регулярные выражение не могу использовать у меня версия 2.0.2

Comment: у меня вот так urls.py path('<int:id>/', post_detail, name='detail'),

Comment: Представление голосования должно быть отдельным от представления отображения статьи. А регулярные выражения в 2.0 использовать можно с [re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path). Впрочем, можно и без них.